# (node) Hit max file limit. Increase "ulimit -n"

Tags: netstat, ulimit, node.js

In Ubuntu 9 I am receiving a message on my server that says:

```
(node) Hit max file limit. Increase "ulimit -n"
```

However, typing commands in the terminal reveals the following:

```
$ ulimit       
unlimited
$ ulimit -n      
65535
```

And a `netstat` reveals I only have ~1000 connections open.

How is it possible I am hitting my limit of 65535 despite `netstat` saying I have 1000 active connections? Does anyone see a server config issue I might be overlooking or have tips for debugging further?

Comment: Where are you seeing this message ?

Answer (score 3):

`ulimit -n` displays the maximum number of open file descriptors, not the maximum number of network connections. You may want to use `lsof -p <PID_OF_node.js>` to figure out what files it has open. My guess is that your node.js code has some logic flaws.

Comment: Actually, opened network socket IS file descriptor as well. So `ulimit -n` controlls how many local files + network sockets + any other descriptors could be opened by a single process/user.

Comment: True. I mentioned open files because we already know at most how many network sockets the process has open; at any rate, `lsof` will display them all.

Answer (score 2):

Typing `ulimit -n` in terminal shows current limit, effective to your current session.
If you've changed limit after compaining daemon start, limits for that daemon was not affected. So you'll need to stop/start daemon. But make sure that limits are not chaning in daemon's init script.

Also, you might want add something like this:

```
*               soft    nofile          2048
*               hard    nofile          2048
```

to /etc/security/limits.conf, so you don't have to `ulimit -n` manually each time.